# Resolving duplicate test idiom in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, coding-style, junit, xunit

I have 2 cases which seem like the same problem to me, even though they're completely different situations:

1) I'm testing both the read and write of an object to the database. Because I'm cleaning up and rebuilding the object each time, the write test needs to read to confirm the write of each field, and the read test is writing first, so the tests end up looking identical.  Yet I don't want to leave a major method in the interface untested.

2) In a much smaller case, I'm testing a copy() method and an equals() method for a small data object. The copy() method is using equals() to test itself, and the equals() method is testing against a copy.  Again, tests are duplicated.

I feel like I'm missing something here, some way to separate the dependency without creating a whole lot of extra work (like having raw JDBC write to the database, etc.)  Is there a standard way to deal with this kind of test duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this sort of test is a code smell. The question is always: What *exactly* does this test test? For this test, what do you trust and what don't you trust?

For me, you can't trust read() and write() together, they are probably in the same class, written by the same person. So if you're testing read() by calling write(), then this isn't a good test, you're testing that write() and read() are in sync, not that they do what they should be doing.

In the second example, you're testing that copy and equals are in sync, same problem.

Lets say this was the implementation of the persistence layer:

```
public class PersistenceLayer {
    private Object object;

    void write(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    Object read(Long id) {
        return object;
    }
}
```

The question is, would your tests pass with this persistence layer? But it obviously doesn't do what you want. It doesn't go near a database. In a similar vein, would your tests pass if your read & write shared a session/transaction? In this case, the data may never be actually committed to the database. It may do a rollback at the end. But your tests will still pass.

Reading your description, you're testing that when I call write() and then read(), I get a similar object back. What I would expect from a write() method is that it writes data to the database. So if I'm testing *that*, I need to check that. So I have to have another channel which I can use to test the read & write. This usually ends up as create a new Connection via JDBC and do a select.

So my testing code would be

```
testWrite() {
    write(o);
    Object o2 = readByJdbc("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?", o);
    assertObjectsEqual(o, o2); // this needs to compare all values
}

testRead() {
    write(o);
    Object o2 = read(o.id);
    Object o3 = readByJdbc("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?", o);

    assertObjectsEqual(o2, o3); // this needs to compare all values
}
```

testWrite() writes to the database and ensures that the data is written to the database by opening a JDBC connection and reading that way (different session, different transaction, i.e the data will be in the database).

testRead() writes to the database and compares the two objects returned by read via the persistence layer and via jdbc. I am duplicating the call to write(o) but it's acceptable because we know whether write will work when the other test gets called. I could write another writeByJdbc, but all I would gain is that one test would fail instead of two.

In fact, depending upon you level of paranoia, you don't need to compare all values in the assertObjectsEqual(). If you're using hibernate for example, you could just assume that everything is declared correctly, and test for the existence of the row in the database. I do this often, because I trust hibernate. But in that case, I need to test how I call hibernate, how the objects are defined.

The jdbc code doesn't need to be long and complex, for a simple select, I just create a List of Maps of columns to values:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> resultSetToListMap(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            map.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
        }

        list.add(map);
    }

    return list;
}
```

This is more than sufficient for most tests.

Comment: Hopefully more of a bad practice than a code smell.  These tests have actually worked very well for me.  I may disagree with you a bit, and I don't have a conceptual answer to my question of duplication, but thank you for all the thought and effort, it gives me some good ideas.  This iPad is not letting me separate paragraphs so I have several comments...

Comment: "what am I really testing" helps me with the equals/copy question.  I'm trying to test the copy so I need to break it down further rather than just use equals.

Comment: What your counterexample is describing is basically a mock. If I don't know enough about the code to know if it's connecting externally, then things are really out of control. Your suggestion is basically to write a separate persistence layer, which is what I'm trying to get aroud by using Hibernate in the first place. And any generic solution I could think of like reading and testing by column would be both too much work and brittle (column order).

Comment: That said, I like the idea of testing the row in the DB for the write test. It gives me something different to test without going overboard. I trust Hibernate, but I don't trust my mapping of each field, so I do need to test each field in either the write or the read test.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As a superficial test, what you are doing is fine. After all, what you want to do is assert that the write method and the read methods are complementary, and when you write and read you obtain an object that is equal (and the same applies for copy and equals)
Unfortunately, I don't think you can go deeper without the extra work, as you already know. A test should be so simple that you shouldn't need an extra test for it, and unless you write a second implementation of write and read, you have to do the manual work.